# Fourier coefficients of sine waveform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

$$v(t)=0\space if \space -T/2\le t<0$$
$$\space sin(\omega_0t)\space if\space0 \le t<T/2$$

$$\omega_0=\frac{2\pi}{T}$$
Given the above waveform i need to find the fourier coefficients $a_0,a_n,b_n.$ Can I get help on how to start solving this?

Comment: How did you proceed with the integration so far? Shift the wave at first by $T/4$ to make it even so that $b_n$ vanish

Comment: How to start solving this is very easy : Learn a lesson on Fourier series. They are a lot of material on the web . http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series .